# Maven dependencies on release

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm trying to make a release with maven. I got one project `ws-client` in `2.4-SNAPSHOT` (I allready have released this one).

This project is in dependencies of `metier` project (still in `2.3-SNAPSHOT`). Here is the dependency in pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I'm trying to release the `metier` project, I got this error :

```
Cannot start a release due to snapshot dependencies :
dependency - ws-client
```

I tried to change the version tag with `${project.version}` or `${project.parent.version}`, I allways have the error.

Please if you know what to do ?

Comment: If you have released the one you have to change the version to a release one which i assume being `2.4` ....

Comment: Yes this is it, works with 2.3 which is the release version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can not do a release of a project which depends on projects in Snapshot version.

Maybe this could help to configure your pom.xml

[how to release a project which depends on a 3rd party SNAPSHOT project in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245932/how-to-release-a-project-which-depends-on-a-3rd-party-snapshot-project-in-maven)

Comment: Thanks this is it ! It shouldn't have finishe the release of ws-client, to stay in the release version.